# Xpath : how to extract link name using xpath

Tags: xpath

```
<table class="genre-table" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td width="50%">
       <h3>
            <a href="http://www.imdb.com/genre/action/?ref_=gnr_mn_ac_mp">Action <span class="normal">»</span>
            </a>     
       </h3>
```

I want to extract the word action from this , how to write the relevant xpath , please help

I tried with this but nothing is getting printed just blank -->

```
    print genre.xpath('//*[@class="genre-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/h3/a/text()')
```

Comment: If you're getting that text from your browser, rather than from a tool such as curl, I suggest looking again -- browsers change the DOM from the raw content read.

Comment: Also, it's very plausible that this content may be in a namespace that you aren't mentioning in the query -- but the subset of the document you gave isn't sufficient to confirm or reject the theory. Look into whether a parent has an `xmlns=` attribute.

Comment: No no parent has that attribute

Comment: Here's the thing -- I take only the code you pasted here, add the missing close tags, run the query you gave, and it works. Next time you're asking a question, make sure you're actually providing enough information **to reproduce the problem**.

Comment: Thank u very much , i found the bug in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works as given:

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> content='''
<table class="genre-table" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td width="50%">
       <h3>
            <a href="http://www.imdb.com/genre/action/?ref_=gnr_mn_ac_mp">Action <span class="normal"></span>
            </a>
       </h3></td></tr></tbody></table>'''
>>> genre = lxml.etree.fromstring(content)
>>> print genre.xpath('//*[@class="genre-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/h3/a/text()')
['Action ', '\n            ']
```

There are two common causes for this turn of events:

1. You're building your query from a view of the DOM given to you by a browser, so your actual document doesn't match what you cut-and-pasted here. Browsers lie (or, rather, reformat HTML to match the idealized DOM model). Use `curl | less`.
2. There are XML namespaces defined in other parts of this document not given here. Specify them in your query, if they exist.